# style a search box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search, css, boot-strap

I have added a search box web part in a custom page layout in SharePoint online, I am using bootstrap

I am trying to make the width of the search box smaller using css but whenever I do the results are not what I am hoping for. Here is the search box on the right

[image]

Any type of styling the width seems to bring the icon down and search box stays the same width as you can see in the next image. 
[image]

This is my HTML

```
<!-- Start Section 1 -->
<div class="section">
<div class="container">
<!-- 2 column Web Part zones -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Stories" ID="TopLeft
<ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>  </div>
<div id="people-finder-container" class="col-md-6">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="PeopleFinder" ID="TopRight
<ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>  </div>
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- End Section 1 -->
```

The css i have tried is pretty straightforward

```
#people-finder-container
{width:50px}
```

When that didnt work I tired to access the web part directly using using the web part ID

```
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5
 {width:50px}
```

Still it gave me the same result. Any help in solving this would be much appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: Added content when inspecting search box element -

```
        <div id="people-finder-container" class="col-md-6">
        <div class="ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth">
        <div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5" class="s4-wpcell-plain ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth ">
        <div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
        <div webpartid="552f3049-1974-4968-a9b9-0a02385fdbba" haspers="false" id="WebPartWPQ5" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " allowdelete="false" style=""><div style="display: none;"></div>
        <div componentid="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr" id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr">
        <div id="SearchBox" name="Control" class="ms-floatLeft">
        <div class="ms-srch-sbLarge ms-srch-sb-border" id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_sboxdiv">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="2048" accesskey="S" title="Search..." id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_sbox" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" onkeypress="if (Srch.U.isEnterKey(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) { $getClientControl(this).search(this.value);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event); }" onkeydown="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.activateDefaultQuerySuggestionBehavior();" onfocus="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.hidePrompt();ctl.setBorder(true);" onblur="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.showPrompt();ctl.setBorder(false);" class="ms-textLarge ms-srch-sbLarge-fullWidth ms-srch-sb-prompt ms-helperText">
        <a title="Search" class="ms-srch-sb-searchLink" id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_SearchLink" onclick="$getClientControl(this).search($get('ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_sbox').value);" href="javascript: {}">                  <img src="/_layouts/15/images/searchresultui.png?rev=41" class="ms-srch-sbLarge-searchImg" id="searchImg" alt="Search">                </a>
        <div class="ms-qSuggest-container ms-shadow" id="AutoCompContainer">                    <div id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_AutoCompList">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SearchOptions">        </div>
        </div><noscript>&lt;div id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_noscript"&gt;It looks like your browser does not have JavaScript enabled. Please turn on JavaScript and try again.&lt;/div&gt;</noscript>
        <div id="ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba">
        </div><div class="ms-clear"></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you paste the content after you inspect the Search box using browser?

Comment: No problem I'll add it to the question

Comment: Try selecting the webpart container div with "`#people-finder-container [webpartid]`" (which will select any webpart inside that div, you can give it a specific `webpartid` GUID value to narrow things down some more if needed), would also be worth a shot to try setting `max-width`

Comment: It works for me if I apply the width on `#SearchBox`. I checked styling the main search box btw.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, they helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it. Looks like it was the inner part of the search box not resizing -

[image]

this was the code I used

```
#ctl00_ctl44_g_552f3049_1974_4968_a9b9_0a02385fdbba_csr_sbox
{
Width:200px
}
```

I didn't expect this to work or if it is even best practice but it is

- A. working
- B. working with bootstrap just fine.

Thanks for everyone's comments they got me thinking and I was able to find the solution.